# excluding twitter handles while using twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

while analyzing tweets on #flipkart using twitteR package in R, most of the tweets are news on offers, by about 2-3 handles. this does not help evaluate the overall sentiment about flipkart. can I exclude these 2-3 handles while extracting the tweets? I need customer response,not news on offers.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a simple solution to your problem. You'll have to process the whole stream and somehow identify the tweets that are news/offers to discard them. One simple step could be to discard tweets from some users, e.g. @flipkart, and you could even remove them upfront in your twitter query, but still, you will have to do a lot of post-processing....

Comment: right now, being able to discard the tweets of some users upfront would be sufficient. can you tell me how that can be done? I have gone through the twitteR package documents from CRAN, but am not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a hint, not a full solution (which I don't think it is feasible). However it is far too long for a comment.

Take a look to twitter api docs, how to search, paragraph [query operators](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search). If you prepend a `-` to a term you exclude it from your query.

This translates to `twitteR` simply at your search query, as follows:

```
searchTwitter("#flipkart -pricetrak", n=10)
```

You can try to exclude some of your terms, but it is not going to be an easy task.

Besides, you should not do e.g. `#flipkart -@flipkart`, since most of customer's comments seem to be addressed to the user `@flipkart`, and you would loose them. (The terms of the search query are interpreted as either users or content of the tweet.)

As a final note, you've got only up to 500 characters in your search query.

Hope it helps somehow.

**UPDATE**

As per comments, I propose some other easy actions you could take. But I'm afraid there is no "magic bullet" and you should play with the data and do lots of trials. Also, it is important to note that `twitteR`library, although it is very useful, it's a bit more tricky to use when doing more "advanced" stuff (actually every twitter library is a bit like that in my experience, and sometimes you end up needing to access to Twitter REST API directly; in a way it makes sense, since libraries make the common tasks really straightforward, like fetching tweets, but are not necessarily easy for other tasks).

1. Skip tweets from certain users, or from users that are verified

This is a toy example of how do you access to the user that sent the tweet:

```
tweets = searchTwitter("#flipkart -pricetrak", n=10)

for (tweet in tweets) {
  screenName <- as.data.frame(tweet)$screenName
  print(screenName)
  tuser <- getUser(screenName)
  verified <- as.data.frame(tuser)$verified
  print(verified)
}
```

This way you could filter the tweets from `@flipkart` for example, or from a list of users that you know that are not customers. And also, you could assume that the customers are not usually verified users (see [here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/119135?lang=en) for more details on verified accounts) and just filter the tweets from them.

2. Skip tweets that have a link in its text

It would be weird (though now impossible of course) that a customer sends a link in its tweet. You could filter them in a similar way:

```
for (tweet in tweets) {
  text <- as.data.frame(tweet)$text
  print(text)
  print(length(strsplit(text, "https://")[[1]]))
}
```

(Where of course if length of the `strsplit` is 1, there is no links in the text of the tweet).

In this way you will filter some tweets that actually are from real customers, but I gather this would be an easy way to filter most of the tweets that include an offer or deal (*all* of them include a link).

Hope it is useful.

**UPDATE 2**

After comments, an improved version of the code,

```
data <- NULL
ads <- NULL
for (tweet in tweets) {
  tweet_df <- as.data.frame(tweet)
  screenName <- tweet_df$screenName
  tuser <- getUser(screenName)
  verified <- as.data.frame(tuser)$verified
  print(verified)
  if (verified == TRUE) {
    ads <- rbind(ads, tweet_df)    
  } else {
    data <- rbind(data, tweet_df)    
  }
}
if (! is.null(ads)) {
  write.table(ads, file = "ads.csv", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
}
if (! is.null(data)) {
  write.table(data, file = "data.csv", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: thanks, it did help getting more user tweets, though tweets about deals still do clutter up the list. I tried converting the data into a .csv file,so as to  remove them, but am not able to identify any parameters to use as filter. could you suggest a method?

Comment: I've updated the answer proposing some more actions. But please take into account there is no "magic bullet". Hope it is useful.

Comment: @Irnzcig based on your hint, I have tried to segregate the verified results. But I get "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)".My modification is:
`> for (tweet in tweets) { screenName <- as.data.frame(tweet)$screenName 
# print(screenName) 
>tuser <- getUser(screenName)
> verified <- as.data.frame(tuser)$verified
 # print(verified)
> if( verified == TRUE){ write.csv(tweet, file = "ads.csv", append =TRUE) }
> if( verified == FALSE){ write.csv(tweet, file = "data.csv",append = TRUE) } 
}`

Comment: Hi, I don't think your modifications cause the error, the problem must be at the operation `as.data.frame`. Do you get a proper `tuser`? Probably you error message is a bit longer, something like "cannot coerce class XXX to data.frame`??

Comment: yes, the error says  `cannot coerce class "structure("status", package = "twitteR")" to a data.frame`. Moreover it also says that write.csv cannot append. If that is the case, then I will be left with only one entry...

Comment: I've updated my answer. But please, next time, your problem was actually unrelated to the original question, it was just a formatting problem when using `write.csv`. Thus you should have opened a new question (after some investigation on your own of course). Additionally, it is not efficient to open and close the output file every time, I've modified your original code. Regards.

Comment: Thanks @Irnzig your answer has helped me a lot. and i am sorry that I got caught up in my problem and asked a question unrelated to the original one. I am new both to R and the forums, so hope I am forgiven this time.

Comment: Hey, no problem! Of course you are starting in the site. Everybody makes lots of minor mistakes at the beginning. Just keep it up!