# How to convert twitter links in id in R twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I have a dataset with 4000 twitter links 
https://twitter.com/finkd
http://twitter.com/moskov
...
I want to get these people id's to work with it in twitteR. I found how to do it manually. However, i need to get id's for everyone.
How can I do it?

Comment: Could you add some code that you have written so far?

Comment: actually I only managed to get access token to twitter and then manually converted several links to id.  The final goal is to get list of people who all these users follow 
crantastic = getUser('00000000')
crantastic$getFollowerIDs(n=NULL) 
crantastic$getFriendIDs(n=NULL)

Comment: I agree, please always post the code for your best attempt. There's quiet a few answers around that might solve your problem, take a look for example to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129208/excluding-twitter-handles-while-using-twitter/35151682#35151682)

Comment: It helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. It was necessary just to use str_replace function.

CAtwitter1=dplyr::mutate(CAtwitter, twitter_screen_name = str_replace(CAtwitter$twitter_url, "https://twitter.com/", " "))

CAtwitter1$twitter_screen_name <- str_replace(CAtwitter1$twitter_screen_name, "http://twitter.com/", " ")